# Cypress tests - check the element value on the last table row

Tags: cypress, cypress-detached-from-dom

I'm doing some cypress tests on a rails/react app and **I need to check if the value inputted in the form on the last row is, lets say, "Another Random Text"**. In the provided html below, it's on the 2nd row but it could be in any other last row number.

---- CYPRESS ----

**What didn't work**

```js
cy.get('.form-something').last().should('have.value', 'Another Random Text')
```

because it returns *cy.should() failed because this element is detached from the DOM.*

And by using `eq()` I couldn't address the last row, just the first or the 2nd last.

Can anyone shine a light?
Thank you in advance

---- HTML ------

```html
<table class="table table-flat">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th style="width: 50%;">State</th>
         <th>Generic State</th>
         <th style="min-width: 100px;"></th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr class="index-0" data-qa="s-3313">
         <td><input class="form-something" type="text" name="name" value="Random Text"></td>
         <td data-qa="generic-state">Additional</td>
         <td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-qa="remove-state"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="index-1" data-qa="s-3314">
         <td><input class="form-something" type="text" name="name" value="Another Random Text"></td>
         <td data-qa="generic-state">Other</td>
         <td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-qa="remove-state"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="2"></td>
         <td><button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-qa="add-new-state"><i class="fa fa-plus mr-2"></i>Add</button></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: There could be a few reasons. Maybe there is a request made to fetch the last row with `Another Random Text`. It's good to have assertions sprinkled throughout. This goes more into depth
https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/detached/

Answer (score 2):

If the table get's re-displayed after the text is entered (or some other action like clicking "Add"), elements you query ***before the action*** are discarded by the app and replaced by a new version.

Your test still has a reference to the original element, so it's not yet garbage-collected but it is detached from the DOM

So this fails,

```js
cy.get('.form-something').last()
  .type('Another Random Text')                   // action causes detached element
  .should('have.value', 'Another Random Text')
```

but this ***maybe*** succeeds

```js
cy.get('.form-something').last()
  .type('Another Random Text')

cy.get('.form-something').last()
  .should('have.value', 'Another Random Text')
```

but it's safer to include the full table selector

```js
cy.get('table tbody tr td .form-something').last()
  .should('have.value', 'Another Random Text')     // requery all parts from table down
```

Comment: Your first suggestion didn't work and the second one with a minor tweek, did work. I had to add a "find" to be able to point to ".form-something". Thank you

Comment: Just an update that I didn't need the "find", I just added "input.form-something" instead of plain ".form-something"

Comment: Interesting, there's something more going on there perhaps a random factor.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `.contains()` based on the "Other" text

```js
cy.get('table').should('be.visible')
  .contains('td', 'Other')                     // locate by text 
  .prev()                                      // previous cell
  .find('input.form-something')                // get the input
  .should('have.value', 'Another Random Text')
```

Comment: Later I found out that the text "other" may be found in multiple rows but other than that, it did work. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Using an `alias` may help your test.

```js
cy.get('.form-something').last().as('lastInput')
cy.get('@lastInput').should('have.value', 'Another Random Text')
```

It looks a bit unnecessary, but `alias` has built-in protection against **detached-from-dom** errors.

Here is one of the Cypress tests that verifies the feature,

```js
it('can find a custom alias again when detached from DOM', () => {
  cy
  .get('foobarbazquux:last').as('foo')   // creating an alias
  .then(() => {
    // remove the existing foobarbazquux
    cy.$$('foobarbazquux').remove()      // detaching from DOM

    // and cause it to be re-rendered
    cy.$$('body').append(cy.$$('<foobarbazquux>asdf</foobarbazquux>'))
  }).get('@foo').should('contain', 'asdf') 
})
```

Comment: Interesting. It asserted correctly. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

One safe bet when dealing with *element is detached from the DOM* errors is to leverage the cypress retry-ability in a proper way.

The trick is to make sure that selecting action is right next to the assertion. In your example that's not the case, because it's broken by the `.last()` call.

You can try something like this, which should do the trick:

```
cy.get('.form-something[value="Another Random Text"]').should('exist')
```

To explain the reasoning behind the answer above: frameworks like React usually load the empty table first, and then fill it up (rerender it). Cypress being too fast often grabs the empty table before its filled, which is afterward rerendered when table data is fetched, resulting in that detached error.

## Edit

To solve a problem mentioned in the comment, when you need control of value **property** rather than value **attribute**, you can use this:

```
cy.get('.form-something').should(inputElements => {
    expect(inputElements[inputElements.length - 1]).to.have.value('Some test');
});
```

This will make sure that the last `.form-something` element contains the right text, and it won't match even if that exact text is in any element other than the last. You can even add multiple assertions that would all together benefit from build-in retry-ability.

Comment: The element is an input, so unfortunately `cy.contains()` won't work. But the principle is correct, so maybe the example should be `cy.get('.form-something:last').should('have.value', 'Another Random Text')`? Although - `:last` is deprecated but may still work.

Comment: True, that's what happens when you want a quick answer without testing it :D Updated the answer, thanks.

Comment: Sorry that one won't work either `[value="Another Random Text"]` tests the attribute `value` but `.type()` changes the ***property*** `value` and does not update the attribute (think of attribute `value` as the placeholder text).

Comment: Thanks for that as well, and good point. Since the provided example code uses value **attribute**, I extended the answer with additional code.

Comment: In this particular scenario, your last edited version works. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an `each` loop to find the element with the desired value and then apply the assertion like this:

```js
cy.get('.form-something')
  .should('be.visible')
  .each(($ele) => {
    if ($ele.val().trim() == 'Another Random Text') {
      cy.wrap($ele).should('have.value', 'Another Random Text') //Apply assertion
      return false //Exit loop once element is found
    }
  })
```

Comment: Just to let you know that it returns the following error: cy.get(...).should(...).ele is not a function

Comment: Just a typo `.each(($ele) => {`